# How does network manager identify a connection over usb0?

Tags: usb, network-manager

Here's a thing I'm trying to solve: I have a PC running Ubuntu 14.04 and an ARM board running some Linux. I want to have RNDIS-ethernet-over-USB connection between the two, and I want network manager to automatically set the connection for me on PC side.

**Board side:** `usb0` is up and running. Every time with the same MAC and IP.

**PC side:** NM-applet is showing "connecting..." status on usb cable plugin, I can chose IPv4 manual config in GUI tool and set the IP address I want. It works. This way I have already got "Wired connection **9**".

So why does NM create another "Wired connection (n+1)" every time I power cycle the board or re-`modprobe g_ether` on the board? What makes it create new connection instead of using an existing one? How does network manager identify a connection over `usb0` on PC side?